# Exp:resso Store Send Orders to Supplier

Tags: expresso-store, add-on

I have a client that I am implementing Exp:resso Store for. The client does not keep the items for in stock but rather orders them directly from the supplier once an order is placed and the supplier ships directly to the customer. Does anyone know if Exp:resso Store has such a capability to send order confirmations to the supplier once the customer has placed the order and payment is confirmed? This capability would also need to be able to bundle all items from an order to a single supplier if it so happens as client wouldn't want the supplier to get multiple requests for the same order.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, I am going to explain a bit of what happens to help clarify.

- Emails are linked and sent out based upon order status.
- Orders can transition through multiple order status and therefor send out multiple emails. - By default Store creates an order status of "New" and sets that as the default order status.
- There is also a generic email template that is created and linked to the status of "New".
- When the user places the order and has a valid payment the order is considered complete and the default status is applied to the order and the linked email is sent out.

So if you wanted your supplier to know that the user has placed an order you can set them up as a BCC recipient in the email template settings for the email template that you have linked to the default status.

Comment: Sounds perfect Justin. My only problem is that if the order contains items from multiple suppliers. Say for example a customer order 2 hard drives and 1 monitor. The 2 hard drives are from one supplier and the monitor from another. I would need two individual emails to go to the suppliers with only what they need to supply. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In that case there is not a way built into Store that would allow you to do this

Comment: Do you know if there is a plugin available or would I have to build a custom module to get this accomplished?

Comment: You would need to build a custom module or extension to allow something like this. Check out the extension hooks available http://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html.

Comment: You might also checkout ObjectiveHTML's Postmaster add-on as a starting point